# How to achieve the background color apply for last row with last input element

Tags: html, css

unable to set the background color for only last element in a row, i tried last-child css properties, but not able to fix. please suggest any other approach is there.

```
<div  id= "row" class="Row">
                <label>Row1:</label>
                <div  id= "CCol1" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1"  class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol2" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol3" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol4" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol5" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Above code**:
i need to apply background color for last row in last input only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this is what you want.

```
.Row .CCol:last-child input:last-child {
  background: #003;
  color: #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Legk4sd1/4/

```css
.Row .CCol:last-child input:last-child {
  background: #003;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div  id= "row" class="Row">
                <label>Row1:</label>
                <div  id= "CCol1" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1"  class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol2" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol3" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol4" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol5" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

- First, you need to target `last-child` of `CCol`
- After that, Target `last-child` of `input` of that particular `CCol`

To sum up, You can use Something like this

```
.Row .CCol:last-child input:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the working snippet

```css
.Row .CCol:last-child input:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div  id= "row" class="Row">
                <label>Row1:</label>
                <div  id= "CCol1" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1"  class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol2" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol3" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol4" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
                <div  id= "CCol5" class="CCol">
                    <input type="text" class="width100"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CHeight"><input type="number" placeholder="1" value="1" class="CWidth">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct then this should work

```
.CCol:last-child input {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.CCol:last-child .CWidth {
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
```

First, you have to take last child of .CCol and after you can take class name of last input. You have a class name in last row's input so no need to take last child for that

Hope this will help you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use last-of-type

```
div div: last-of-type .CCol{
    backgroung-color:red;
}
```